# Android LED_NOTIFICATION_ID cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, notifications, led

I've looked for examples on how to get the android device LED to blink and I've gotten the message about not being able to resolve LED_NOTIFICATION_ID to a variable. My code is below. Is there anyone that can tell me why I'm receiving this error?

```
private void redFlashLight(Context context)
    {
        NotificationManager nm = ( NotificationManager ) context.getSystemService( context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
        Notification notif = new Notification();
        notif.ledARGB = 0xFFff0000;
        notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        notif.ledOnMS = 100; 
        notif.ledOffMS = 100; 
        notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
        nm.notify(LED_NOTIFICATION_ID, notif);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't declared `LED_NOTIFICATION_ID` as a variable then. Look for misspellings. Is it supposed to be qualified with a class name?

Comment: Based on the example I saw, I assumed it was a built-in variable. It wasn't defined in their code. Thanks for your help!